Are these two homophones (思考 and 嗜好) pronounced differently here somehow to differentiate them?
This clip is from Hanamonogatari, where the speaker (Kanbaru) is lamenting over how a former basketball player (in front of her) has been pretending to grant the wishes of people worrying about various life issues. The former player argues that time heals all wounds, so by just letting the person in question have their story heard they tend to get better over time.
Kanbaru thinks the former player just enjoys hearing those stories and thinks it is unethical to lie to those people and objects that their thought (process) [思考] and how they seem to have a liking for hearing these stories [嗜好] are not things to be praised:

その思考も その嗜好も
とてもじゃないけれど 理解できないが
しかし 人を不幸に陥れる類いの行為でもなさそうだしな

思考 and 嗜好 are both pronounced しこう{LHH}, but it seems that 嗜好 is said with a higher intonation in this clip.
I found some sound clips on Forvo suggesting し in 嗜好 isn't devoiced like 思考, but in this clip both are clearly devoiced.
To me without subtitles there would be no foolproof way to determine what each しこう refers to (considering 志向 also is common and could perhaps work here but I am not sure).
I have considered several possibilities of how someone could tell them apart without the kanji but each of them leaves me with two major questions:

Is the usage of a higher intonation on the second しこう just a pattern of listing several options/aspects (like how in English saying "there's this and that..." often puts different intonation on this and that respectively), or is this actually a way to differentiate between the two しこう? Is this an intentional thing native speakers may do to differentiate homophone nouns when surrounding word context may be insufficient?
After hearing the first しこう, which I'd imagine most natives to understand as 思考, would any native speaker perhaps misunderstand the second しこう as any other homophone like 志向? Or perhaps, this usage of homophones was somewhat deliberate for ambiguity and/or comedic effect? I remember a similar thing in Hunter x Hunter where Kurapika is bound to the rules of a certain ability and called it 「制約と誓約」, which from context "restriction" and "oath" go hand-in-hand, but from my non-native perspective I viewed it as a little tongue-in-cheek. If this question needs more context I can provide it.


She pronounced 嗜好 with a little emphasis or emotion, but the two しこう are pronounced exactly the same under normal circumstances. Even native speakers cannot tell them apart without the aid of context.
In this context, probably most native speakers can eventually arrive at the same interpretation of "思考も嗜好も理解できない". 指向, 施行, 試行, 歯垢, 至高, and so on make no sense. 志向 might make sense, but it's rarely used in this context. However, it does require a few moments to reach this conclusion. Unless she intended a pun (and she doesn't seem to have done so), this sentence should usually be rephrased to something like 考え方も好みも理解できない.
I can only speculate about why such a puzzling expression was broadcast. Maybe the original author created this text without much consideration for pronunciation, and everyone else chose to let it go. Recently, there's been a trend in anime adaptations to faithfully reproduce scenes from the original work without alterations. I wonder if such a tendency might have played a role in this weird situation.

The monogatari series is full of verbal and visual wordplay with little regard for the viewer's ability to keep up, so this seems on brand.
